# Android Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout calling hide on rememberModalBottomSheetState object causing overlay hanging with JobCancellationException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Android Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout, when calling `hide()` on `rememberModalBottomSheetState` object it causes an overlay hang periodically.

The exception being thrown is

> CancellationException nested kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: ScopeCoroutine was cancelled; job=ScopeCoroutine{Cancelled}@5ef8661

What is the reason for this being called and/or is there an efficient way to retry hiding the Bottom Sheet Dialog when the exception is thrown?

```
@Composable
fun ExampleUi(
    exampleBotttomSheetState: ExampleBottomSheetState,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) {
    
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
    )
    
    when (exampleBotttomSheetState.value) {
        is ExampleBottomSheetState.Hide -> {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                bottomSheetScaffoldState.hide()
            }
        }
        is ExampleBottomSheetState.Show -> {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                bottomSheetScaffoldState.show()
            }
        }
    }


    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            // Bottom Sheet Content UI
        }
    ) {
        // UI content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s best not to be launching coroutines in a composable like this. Recomposition can happen for many reasons and frequently, so that would trigger the when block many times.

I recommend passing in the modalBottomSheetState directly and modifying it at the source instead of having the logic in a Composable.

Example here: https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/material/modalbottomsheetlayout/

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun ModalBottomSheetSample() {
    val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = state,
        sheetContent = {
            LazyColumn {
                items(50) {
                    ListItem(
                        text = { Text("Item $it") },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Default.Favorite,
                                contentDescription = "Localized description"
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text("Rest of the UI")
            Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
            Button(onClick = { scope.launch { state.show() } }) {
                Text("Click to show sheet")
            }
        }
    }
}
```